# Special characters in SSIS

Tags: csv, ssis

I'm loading a CSV file to the SSIS with special characters and i need the same special characters to be written in the database.But at the moment For example,
 "**Alfred Kärcher GmbH & Co. KG**" has been changed to "**Alfred KÃ¤rcher GmbH & Co. KG**".its written to the databse incorrectly.Is there a way to stop the character conversion in SSIS?
How can i sort this out? I don't have any flat file connection.I have tried so many ways but didn't work out.

[image] [image]

Thank you

Comment: What data source do you have in your data flow for your CSV file, if you don't have any flat file connection?

Comment: i have OLEDB source

Comment: Then please add an example on how your source query looks for the CSV file import

Comment: I have added snaps. Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that the destination table has the correct code? I would insert a data viewer after the initial read to make sure that's where my problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the information in your csv source file has UTF-8 encoding where "ä" character is coded as two bytes: C3 A4 but during the load it was interpreted as ANSI encoding resulting to taking the bytes as separate characters: "Ã" and "¤".
There are two similar methods how to resolve it depending whether your destination table is using varchar or nvarchar data types.
Because it was converted to ANSI Latin1 encoding CP1252 I assume you were using data type type varchar.
Basically you need to read the file using Codepage 65001 (UTF-8), then use Derived Column transformation where you would add a derived column for every text field in the csv file using cast expressions, for example (DT_STR,50,1252)LastName.
Add other derived columns in file for non-integer columns to avoid error "The column  cannot be processed because more than one code page (65001 and 1252) are specified for it"..
On the destination make sure destination columns are mapped to derived columns rather than original columns.

If your destination table has nvarchar type, use Data Conversion instead of Derived Column transformation and select data type Unicode string [DT_WSTR].